# How to choose grid Columns from some Tabs and display them in another Tab?

Tags: c#, wpf, tabs, grid

I'm creating a WPF application(UI) with a TabControl which contains four TabItems in it.
[My Application](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hgR01.png) --
From the [User Tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lenau.png), I want to choose somehow (maybe with a check box, or any other way) which of the GridColumns will be displayed at the User Tab. I can work with the other Tabs, but sometimes I need to give the user the opportunity to work only with the specific outputs he/she wants. How can I make this work? I am new to C# and wpf, so if you could explain a simple solution and offer some codes, I would appriciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Before answering your question, a brief hint for you: when you ask, post some code, otherwise it will be hard that someone spends time for helping you.

For implementing your application you need to consider:

1. [ElementName data binding](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.elementname(v=vs.110).aspx)
2. ElementName data binding can't work in the `ColumnDefinitions` property

To solve the point number 2 you can read this very interesting [article by Josh Smith](https://joshsmithonwpf.wordpress.com/2008/07/22/enable-elementname-bindings-with-elementspy/).

Pratically he creates a special kind of [ElementSpy](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18678/Attaching-a-Virtual-Branch-to-the-Logical-Tree-in) with an attached property:

```
public class ElementSpy : Freezable
{
    private DependencyObject element;

    public static ElementSpy GetNameScopeSource(DependencyObject obj)
    {
        return (ElementSpy)obj.GetValue(NameScopeSourceProperty);
    }

    public static void SetNameScopeSource(DependencyObject obj, ElementSpy value)
    {
        obj.SetValue(NameScopeSourceProperty, value);
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty NameScopeSourceProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("NameScopeSource", typeof(ElementSpy), typeof(ElementSpy),
            new UIPropertyMetadata(null, OnNameScopeSourceProperty));

    private static void OnNameScopeSourceProperty(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args)
    {
        INameScope nameScope;
        ElementSpy elementSpy = args.NewValue as ElementSpy;

        if (elementSpy != null && elementSpy.Element != null)
        {
            nameScope = NameScope.GetNameScope(elementSpy.Element);
            if (nameScope != null)
            {
                d.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action<DependencyObject, INameScope>(SetScope),
                    System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority.Normal,
                    d, nameScope);
            }
        }
    }

    private static void SetScope(DependencyObject d, INameScope nameScope)
    {
        NameScope.SetNameScope(d, nameScope);
    }

    public DependencyObject Element
    {
        get
        {
            if (element == null)
            {
                PropertyInfo propertyInfo = typeof(Freezable).GetProperty("InheritanceContext",
                    BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);

                element = propertyInfo.GetValue(this, null) as DependencyObject;

                if (element != null)
                {
                    Freeze();
                }
            }

            return element;
        }
    }

    protected override Freezable CreateInstanceCore()
    {
        return new ElementSpy();
    }
}
```

Now we can use binding in our XAML

```
<Window.Resources>
    <local:BooleanWidthConverter x:Key="BooleanWidthConverter" />
    <local:ElementSpy x:Key="ElementSpy" />
</Window.Resources>

    <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
    <Grid local:ElementSpy.NameScopeSource="{StaticResource ElementSpy}"
            Margin="0,0,0,30">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="{Binding ElementName=cb1, Path=IsChecked, Converter={StaticResource BooleanWidthConverter}, Mode=OneWay}" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="{Binding ElementName=cb2, Path=IsChecked, Converter={StaticResource BooleanWidthConverter}, Mode=OneWay}" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="{Binding ElementName=cb3, Path=IsChecked, Converter={StaticResource BooleanWidthConverter}, Mode=OneWay}" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center" Text="Column 1" Margin="4" Grid.Column="0" />
        <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center" Text="Column 2" Margin="4" Grid.Column="1" />
        <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center" Text="Column 3" Margin="4" Grid.Column="2" />

    </Grid>

    <CheckBox x:Name="cb1" Content="Column 1" Margin="4" IsChecked="true" HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
    <CheckBox x:Name="cb2" Content="Column 2" Margin="4" IsChecked="true" HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
    <CheckBox x:Name="cb3" Content="Column 3" Margin="4" IsChecked="true" HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
</StackPanel>
```

To complete our code, we need a simple converter:

```
public class BooleanWidthConverter : IValueConverter
{
    private static GridLength star = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Star);
    private static GridLength zero = new GridLength(0, GridUnitType.Pixel);

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        bool boolValue = (bool)value;

        return boolValue ? star : zero;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Of course this is just a sample prototype, but I am sure it can help you with your application.